# Weird problem with Spring MVC, Bean Validation using @Valid and Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring, validation, spring-mvc, javabeans

I have an application uses bean validation in 50 domain classes. It has worked for months without any problems using @Valid in the Spring MVC controllers.

Now all of a sudden, I have made many fields "lazy" in Hibernate to improve performance. I have had to deal with all sorts of weird issues, from equals() method no longer working, to objects being in the session crashing because the data wasn't loaded.

I have come across a very weird problem now where I *am* loading the data into a session attribute on a Spring MVC form, the view renders it properly, but when passed to @Valid, it reports ALL of the fields to have errors even though the data is 100% valid.

```
public class EducationFacility extends DomainObject {

    /* Members */
    @NotEmpty(message = "{educationFacility.name.notEmpty}")
    private String name;

    @Valid
    private Address address = new Address();

    @Pattern(message = "{educationFacility.phoneNumber.valid}",
        regexp = "(\\()?(\\d){3}(\\))?(\\s|-)(\\d){3}(\\s|-)(\\d){4}")
    private String phoneNumber = "";
    ...
}
```

Here's the hibernate definition:

```
<class name="jobprep.domain.educationfacility.EducationFacility" table="education_facility">
    <id name="id" column="education_facility_id" type="long">
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="name" column="name"/>
    <component name="address" class="jobprep.domain.educationfacility.Address">
        <property name="address" column="address"/>
        <property name="postalCode" column="postal_code"/>
        <many-to-one name="province" class="jobprep.domain.educationfacility.Province" column="province_id"  />
    </component>
    <property name="phoneNumber" column="phone_number"/>
    <property name="isEnabled" column="is_enabled"/>
    <property name="homepageViewable" column="homepage_viewable" />
    <property name="coursesCreated" />
    <many-to-one name="admin" class="jobprep.domain.user.Admin" column="admin_id" />
    <many-to-one name="director" class="jobprep.domain.educationfacility.Director"
                 column="director_id" cascade="all" />
    <bag name="teachers" inverse="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan" order-by="username asc">
        <key column="education_facility_id" />
        <one-to-many class="jobprep.domain.teacher.Teacher" />
    </bag>
    <bag name="students" inverse="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan" order-by="username asc">
        <key column="student_education_facility_id" />
        <one-to-many class="jobprep.domain.student.Student"/>
    </bag>
    <bag name="ipRestrictions" inverse="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
        <key column="education_facility_id" />
        <one-to-many class="jobprep.domain.educationfacility.IpRestriction" />
    </bag>
    <bag name="allowedModules" table="education_facility_to_module"
         inverse="false" lazy="true">
        <key column="education_facility_id" />
        <many-to-many class="jobprep.domain.module.Module" column="module_id"/>
    </bag>
</class>
```

Here's the controller definition:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/myEducationFacility")
@SessionAttributes("educationFacility")
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_DIRECTOR')")
public class MyEducationFacilityController extends ControllerSupport {
    ....
}
```

Here's the MVC's save method:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String save(@Valid EducationFacility educationFacility, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status) {
        if(result.hasErrors()) {
            return view("index");
        } else {
            adminService.saveEducationFacility(educationFacility);
            status.setComplete();

            return redirect("?complete=true");
        }
    }
```

Here's the errors Spring is Added to the binding result when save() is invoked by Spring. These are totally wrong:

```
{org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.educationFacility=org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 4 errors
    Field error in object 'educationFacility' on field 'phoneNumber': rejected value [(519) 254-3678]; codes [Pattern.educationFacility.phoneNumber,Pattern.phoneNumber,Pattern.java.lang.String,Pattern]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [educationFacility.phoneNumber,phoneNumber]; arguments []; default message [phoneNumber],[Ljavax.validation.constraints.Pattern$Flag;@29895454,(\()?(\d){3}(\))?(\s|-)(\d){3}(\s|-)(\d){4}]; default message [Must be of the form: ###-###-####]
    Field error in object 'educationFacility' on field 'address.address': rejected value [Windsor]; codes [NotEmpty.educationFacility.address.address,NotEmpty.address.address,NotEmpty.address,NotEmpty.java.lang.String,NotEmpty]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [educationFacility.address.address,address.address]; arguments []; default message [address.address]]; default message [Address may not be empty]
    Field error in object 'educationFacility' on field 'name': rejected value [Catholic School Board]; codes [NotEmpty.educationFacility.name,NotEmpty.name,NotEmpty.java.lang.String,NotEmpty]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [educationFacility.name,name]; arguments []; default message [name]]; default message [Name may not be empty]
    Field error in object 'educationFacility' on field 'address.postalCode': rejected value [N9a 2a5]; codes [Pattern.educationFacility.address.postalCode,Pattern.address.postalCode,Pattern.postalCode,Pattern.java.lang.String,Pattern]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [educationFacility.address.postalCode,address.postalCode]; arguments []; default message [address.postalCode],[Ljavax.validation.constraints.Pattern$Flag;@29895454,[a-zA-Z]\d[a-zA-Z](\s|-)\d[a-zA-Z]\d]; default message [Postal Code must be of the format: a#a-#a#], educationFacility=class jobprep.domain.educationfacility.EducationFacility{id=3}}
```

Help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a guess, but try to set contraint annotations on getters instead of fields. Perhaps state of the fields doesn't match values returned by getters due to some lazy-loading magic.

Comment: I'll give that a try. It is weird because on 2 other forms, the @Valid actually works (education facility registerations, and when an admin adds/edits a new education facility to the system). It only reports the wrong errors when a director is editing their own education facility. And yes, I make sure to call into the service layer and load it out of the database - not using the one in the current user session. This kind of stuff is behind frustrating, and makes me want to throw hibernate out altogether.

Comment: I just sucked it up and made director.educationFacility lazy="false". That was the only thing that worked. Stupid Hibernate. I hate it sometimes. Since you were the only one to bother responding, i'll give you the credit for the answer so you can get the points.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is indeed the constraint placement. Think about it, lazy loading works via proxies and method interception. This only works if you place the constraints on the getter of the entities. The proxies have to be accessed via a method call. If you access the fields directly as you do in your placement of the constraints, Validator is validating the proxies itself. See also https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=1005515 and http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HV-348